# Can any one explain `${}` notation I cannot search that on google

Tags: javascript

Example:
    function greet (name, owner) {
        return `Hello ${name==owner?'boss':'guest'}`
    }

What is that and how does this work?

```
`${}`
```

Comment: Please take some time to [search through and review the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) before asking questions here.

Comment: @Kaiido It's meant as more of a general "you will find these sorts of things outside of asking questions here" rather than a "you should have read the entire MDN reference first", if that's what you mean?

Comment: @Kaiido you are right I try to find that on google but it is not helpful so I posted that here.

Comment: @Marty I had try that and then posted here.

Comment: @HimanshuBisht, next time, for this kind of really improbable to help any future readers (which won't know what to search for either), you may want to try to ask on [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) instead of posting a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Inside `${}` is an expression, which based on your post is a **ternary operator**. Basically if you call `greet()` with the same `name` and `owner` arguments, it will return `'Hello boss'` and otherwise returns `'Hello guest'`.

Another example:

```
var year = 2016;
var birthDate = 1994;
var str = `My age is ${year-birthDate}`; // My age is 22
```

Note that the string is inside **back-ticks/back-quotes**, not single quotes.

Comment: Technically, there is a `Hello ` in the return string.

Comment: @RaxWeber So it's called Template Literal. Thanks Rax :)

Answer (score 0):

${} This is an expression language syntax if your javascript is inside a .jsp file.

Here is the link to know more.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm

Answer (score -1):

the code uses ternary operator
its just equal to:

```js
if(name===owner){
return 'boss';
}
else{
return 'guest'
}
```